# Kendo React GridColumn Menu - returning {false} from a function

Tags: reactjs, kendo-react-ui

I'm trying to hide the Column Menu icon on certain Columns in my Grid.
If I specify the Column as:

```
<GridColumn field={myprops.field} title={myprops.title} 

   columnMenu={false} />
```

Then no menu icon (...) appears in the Column Header - this is what I want, but only on specified Columns

But if I try to use props to determine whether the Column menu should appear at all, I specify the Column as:

```
<GridColumn field={myprops.field} title={myprops.title} 

   columnMenu={(props) => { return (myprops.menu == false) ? false : getMenu(props)}} />
```

Then the menu Icon ellipses appears in the Column header, but when clicked on the menu is empty

Shouldn't this code be the same as specifying `columnMenu={false}` in cases where myprops.menu=false ?